# Throwing error "url or rows or columns is required." C3, D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to run the following snippet but it throws error "url or rows or columns is required." at c3.min.js. Not sure why this is happening because I have followed all the basic steps of C3 as mentioned, any help in this regard would be appreciated

```
<head>
     <!-- Load c3.css -->
     <link href="c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart">

    <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"> </script>
    <script src="c3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
            data: {
                column: [
                    ['data1', 40, 300, 200, 500, 250, 350],
                    ['data2', 60, 30, 20, 50, 55, 35]
                ]
            }
        }
            );
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You typo-ed, column should be column**s**

```
        data: {
            columns: [ // <- There is an S on column
                ['data1', 40, 300, 200, 500, 250, 350],
                ['data2', 60, 30, 20, 50, 55, 35]
            ]
        }
```